# GWT client and spring server with rest APIs

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I am a GWT user and what I appreciate of it is the opportunity to develop web interfaces in Java. 
Currently, a team is developing the server side of a web application that offers rest Apis and that is based on Spring. 
My idea was to use GWT to create the client side application and, rather than invoking some gwt rest apis, I want to invoke, from such client, the rest apis exposed by the spring-based server.

My questions are: does this sound reasonable? Can i just code and cross compile a gwt client invoking the external rest Apps or do I still need  GWT server handing off the requests to the spring-based server? What's a potential deployment scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need GWT server capabilities at all (gwt-server.jar). You only need a web server to host your compiled GWT app like nginx.

What works for me is coding simple REST calls (Spring MVC) from the server and GWT using [GWTP Rest support](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Rest-Dispatch).

Jackson and [GwtJackson](https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson) are used in both sides to serialize/deserialize DTO's.

To avoid [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) problems use a reverse proxy or implement [CORS](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

Comment: Thanks. Why Jackson? What about Gson? Also, do you think I could skip the reverse proxy and deploy the client on the same server as the web app, i.e. Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Spring MVC by default uses MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and GWTJackson is supporting jackson in client. I guess Gson will fit too. You can skip the reverse proxy of course. Deploying the app in tomcat is the easiest way to go.

Comment: Ok. What if I change the approch and plan on this: (1) the user communicates with the Spring-based server; (2) the server dispatches the user's requests to the GWT client; (3) The GWT client makes REST calls to the Spring-based server to get results, e.g. data loaded from a database and elaborated by my business logic; (4) the GWT client prepare the web pages to show to the user and returns them to the Spring-based server; (5) the Spring based server forwards the page to the user. Could this work?

Comment: 4 and 5 are not correct. The user downloads the whole client application in (2). The client repaints itself on user interaction. It's a different approach than JSP's, for instance. GWT client app and spring server only exchange json info!

Comment: So, you say there is no way I can get the user to directly communicate with the spring-based server, which mediates the communication with the GWT client, because one should want the GWT client deployed at the user's? Obviously I still have JSON being exchanged with the spring-based server when invoking the REST APIs.

Comment: I could actually get to work by implementing the CORS filter and creating a servlet that manages the interaction and forwards HTTP requests and responses. Basically, it is acting as a proxy server for simple HTTP request.